# ASP.NET - Change from Web Application Project to Web Site Project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am new to Visual Studio and ASP.NET. I have a MyClass.cs file under App_Code directory, but could not able to run the function in the class file. Keep getting this error:

```
The name 'MyClass' does not exist in the current context
```

I know that code works fine since I posted the codes and others confirmed it works, but I am still receiving the error above.

I read alot more threads on the NET and somes indicated that problem is using Web Application Project instead of Web Site project, which the class file would not compile.  I am not sure if I've created it under Application Project we Web Site project.

How can I tell that my site is running under Web Application Project or Web Site Project?  and How can I change it to Web Site Project so my class can be recognized.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: website or webapp shoudl make no differance as pertains to your error. have you tried putting your MyClass.cs in a folder called 'csharp' (eg: /app_code/csharp/MyClass.cs)?  here are the differances: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I created a csharp folder under App_Code and put the class file in but still getting the sam error.

Comment: Show yor code and screenshot of solution explorer tab

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I went to IIS and selected "Convert to Application" for entire folder, looks like it is working now. I have a quick question if you don't mind to answer. In the IIS (win 2008), I have classic ASP and ASP.NET sites, seperated as folders. any folders for ASP.NET site should "Convert To Application" correct?